# Groovy type conversion

Tags: groovy, type-conversion, casting

In Groovy you can do surprising type conversions using either the `as` operator or the `asType` method. Examples include

```
Short s = new Integer(6) as Short
List collection = new HashSet().asType(List)
```

I'm surprised that I can convert from an Integer to a Short and from a Set to a List, because there is no "is a" relationship between these types, although they do share a common ancestor.

For example, the following code is equivalent to the Integer/Short example in terms of the 
relationship between the types involved in the conversion

```
class Parent {}
class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}

def c = new Child1() as Child2
```

But of course this example fails. What exactly are the type conversion rules behind the `as` operator and the `asType` method?

Answer (score 8):

I believe the default `asType` behaviour can be found in: [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.java](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java)
[org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.java](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java).

Starting from `DefaultGroovyMethods` it is quite easy to follow the behavior of `asType` for a specific object type and requested type combination.

Answer (score 5):

According to what Ruben has already pointed out the end result of:

```
Set collection = new HashSet().asType(List)
```

is

```
Set collection = new ArrayList( new HashSet() )
```

The `asType` method recognizes you are wanting a `List` and being the fact `HashSet` is a `Collection`, it just uses `ArrayList`'s constructor which takes a `Collection`.

As for the numbers one, it converts the `Integer` into a `Number`, then calls the `shortValue` method.

I didn't realize there was so much logic in converting references/values like this, my sincere gratitude to Ruben for pointing out the source, I'll be making quite a few blog posts over this topic.